# EJB JPA insert huge data after reading from Message driven bean

Tags: jpa, insert, batch-processing

I am fetching data from Message driven bean.on message i am getting around 20000 records, when i'm trying to persist to database, Transaction time out is occuring. what are the ways to insert data to database from Message driven bean On message.

Comment: What does this have to do with Windows batch files?

Comment: i have one java application

Comment: i have one java application getting data from differnt application.
after getting through ejb message driven bean storing it to DB.
while storing it to db getting transaction time out is happening.
i cannont increase the transaction time out. i only need to improve performance or write a code to insert the data within the transaction timeout